# Javascript variable in a twig asset

Tags: javascript, twig, assets

I would like to use a document variable in a twig asset like this:

```
var imgName="HelloWorld.png";
document.getElementById("myImgTag").src="url({{asset( imgName) }})";
```

I know this is not working. Is there any manner to pass imgName in the asset field in this spirit?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an asset directory:

like this in the template

```
<script>
    var assetsDir = "{{ asset('assets/') }}"
</script>
```

then in javascript use it like this:

```
var imgName="HelloWorld.png";
```

`document.getElementById("myImgTag").src= assetDir + '/' + imgName`